# Creating object of a class in Java

Tags: java, class, object

I have a syntax question.

I know that object of a class can be created as:

```
MyClass classname = new MyClass();
```

but can is it ok if a do the following:

```
MyClass classname;
//.....some lines of code
classname = new MyClass();
```

Comment: And when you finish testing it, rename the class to begin with uppercase :)

Comment: it's ok as long as you don't try to reference classname before its initialized (compilation error).

Comment: And camel case (MyClass, object className), is a standard convention for Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can instantiate the object on a different line than the type declaration, however it is only useful when you want to instantiate the object in a different scope:

```
Object o;
try {
     o = new Thing();
} catch(Exception e) {
}
o.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can.

After:

`myclass classname;`

Your `classname` refers to `null` or code will not compile if you use it before assigment, as Pshemo said in comment.

You can assign this reference after some other time/operations many times to other objects and also back to null:

```
classname = new myclass();
classname = new myclass();
classname = new child_of_myclass();
classname = other_object_of_classname;
classname = null;
```

Comment: tiny point, the "refers to null" bit doesn't hold for primitives.

Comment: "after `myclass classname;` *classname refers to null*" it is true only if `classname` is field, not if it is local variable of some method. In local variables you need to explicit set it to null, or every try to use this variable will not let code to compile.